# Search Filter en vuejs

Tags: vue.js

Cuando utilizo el buscador, no me toma en cuenta la primera letra a menos que la ponga en mayúscula, estoy utilizando vue.js, vue-cli webpack

Con el siguiente código hago funcionar el search:

```
  computed: {
    filteredPacks: function(){
      return this.packs.filter((pack) => {
        return pack.name.match(this.search);
      })
    }
  },
```

Con este input hago la busqueda:

```
<input type="text" v-model="search" placeholder="search">
```

y esto es lo que hago que busque:

```
<div class="card-body">
  <h4 class="card-title">{{pack.name.toUpperCase()}}</h4>
</div>
```

Pero cuando realizo la búsqueda así, me muestra lo que necesito:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En cambio si quiero buscar lo que tenga la letra a o algo todo con minúscula no me toma en cuenta el que empieza con A mayúscula
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][2]][2]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

que es lo que esta saliendo mal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

la respuesta fue muy simple, solo agregar .toLowerCase() despues del dato deaseado:

```
   filteredPacks: function(){
      return this.packs.filter((pack) => {
        return pack.name.toLowerCase().match(this.search);
      })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Mira este video, aqui hacen una barra de busqueda con vuejs https://youtu.be/fmFAIUtthLo

Comment: Los enlaces no son respuestas. Tienes que escribir tu respuesta aqui